# xyz SplitBy y then Drop y for ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'd like a more efficient way of doing the following:

I have xyz data in the form of `MyList` for which I'd like to plot z as a function of x, split by y.

```
MyList = {
   {1, 1, 0.3}, {2, 1, 0.4}, {3, 1, 0.5},
   {1, 2, 0.7}, {2, 2, 0.85}, {3, 2, 0.9}
   };

List1 = MyList[[1 ;; 3, {1, 3}]];
List2 = MyList[[4 ;; 6, {1, 3}]];

ListLinePlot[{List1, List2}]
```

The best I've come up with is

```
NewList = SplitBy[MyList, Part[#, 2] &][[All, All, {1, 3}]]
ListLinePlot[NewList]
```

which seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be faster than the method in OP for large inputs:

```
TakeList[MyList[[All, {1, 3}]], Length /@ Split[MyList[[All, 2]]]]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 0.3}, {2, 0.4}, {3, 0.5}}, {{1, 0.7}, {2, 0.85}, {3, 0.9}}}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
ml = RandomInteger[10, {100000, 3}];

nl1 = SplitBy[ml, Part[#, 2] &][[All, All, {1, 3}]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.23
> ```

```
nl2 = TakeList[ml[[All, {1, 3}]], Length /@ Split[ml[[All, 2]]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>    0.057
> ```

```
nl1 == nl2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

If the input list is already ordered by the second column (as in the example in OP) you can also use [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) + [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) and [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html)

```
SeedRandom[1]
ml = SortBy[#[[2]] &] @ RandomInteger[10, {100000, 3}];

nl1 = SplitBy[ml, Part[#, 2] &][[All, All, {1, 3}]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.22
> ```

```
nl2 = TakeList[ml[[All, {1, 3}]], Length /@ Split[ml[[All, 2]]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.0073
> ```

```
nl3 = Extract[ml[[All, {1, 3}]], List /@ GatherBy[Range@Length@ml, ml[[#, 2]] &]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.011
> ```

```
nl4 = Values @ GroupBy[ml, #[[2]] &, #[[All, {1, 3}]] &]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.0065
> ```

```
nl5 = Values @ GroupBy[ml, (#[[2]] &) -> ( #[[{1, 3}]] &)]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First (* the version from MarcoB's answer *)
```

> ```
>   0.027
> ```

```
nl1 == nl2 == nl3 == nl4 == nl5
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
GroupBy[MyList, (#[[2]]&) -> (#[[{1,3}]]&)] // Values // ListLinePlot
```

[image]